# Use paypal Express checkout in minimum steps using nvp in asp.net

Tags: paypal

I want to use paypal express checkout in my application in minimum steps
like:
click on paypal button-> verify account on paypal-> back with token to my application ->
confirm the payment->successful msg ->credited into my account(user not redirect to paypal) only get success message on application

currently paypal confirm the payment of user in paypal site but i want it to my application 
and user only once redirect to paypal site for account verification rest all process done in to my backhand side of asp.net application

Comment: What have you tried. You need to show some effort to get most out of this site. Also, you need to narrow down your question to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's the way Paypal works.And where is a call to getExpressCheckoutDetails.
If you want paypal shipping details on your webpage you need to make call to this method.
It will return you shipping detail and then create a button for say "Pay" and call doExpressCheckout method of PaypalAPI to complete your transaction :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as a starting point: https://paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php  (SSL is expired or invalid so you'll have to add security exception, but it works)